# The click event handler added with jQuery's live method gets triggered for a disabled asp.net image button

Tags: jquery

How do I stop a click event handler added with jQuery's live method from getting triggered on an already disabled asp.net image button?

Following is the code snippet.

```
    $('#<%=imgBtnEdit.ClientID%>').live('click', function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `:enabled` pseudo-selector.

```
$('#<%=imgBtnEdit.ClientID%>:enabled').live('click', function () { ... });
```

Comment: But can you let me know why is the event handler being triggered for the disabled button in the first place?

Comment: @surajnaik. The `live` method catch all clicks in the document, even the clicks on disabled buttons, unlike the `bind` method. Check the docs for more information: http://api.jquery.com/live/